# Clicking Links inside my floating div does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, floating

I have these movies and when a movie is clicked a floating div appears.

In this floating div i need to put a link to a video / trailer inside the div when it opens. Any link i put inside that div does not work when clicked. Chrome even shows the link when hovering over the link, but clicking it does nothing.

Also any link outside the floating div works just fine.

How can i fix this?

Please check this demo with running code. Thanks.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/senaru/pen/qBWYQYQ?editors=0010)

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="app">
    <h3>Most Popular Movies</h3>
    <section class="movies">
        <div class="movie">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MDE2ODcwNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzI2NzQ2NzM@._V1_.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
            <div class="title">Avengers: Endgame</div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="length">182 min</span>
                <span class="year">2019</span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                Adrift in space with no food or water, Tony Stark sends a message to Pepper Potts as his oxygen supply starts to dwindle. Meanwhile, the remaining Avengers Thor, Black Widow, Captain America and Bruce Banner must figure out a way to bring back their vanquished allies for an epic showdown with Thanos the evil demigod who decimated the planet and the universe.
                <br>
                <a target="_blank" class="info-btn color small" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMBFSGVi1c"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Play Trailer</a>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMBFSGVi1c">Popup</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="movie">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjU0NDk0N2EtNTliZS00MjNmLTk0M2MtYTMzOTUxMGQwZWI3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzE0MTQ2NzQ@._V1_.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
            <div class="title">Top End Wedding</div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="length">113 min</span>
                <span class="year">2019</span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                Lauren and Ned have 10 days to find Lauren's mother who has gone AWOL in the remote far north of Australia so that they can reunite her parents and pull off their dream wedding.
                <a target="_blank" class="info-btn color small" href="https://www.dolby.com/us/en/cinema"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Play Trailer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movie">
            <img src="https://cineprog.de/images/Breite_400px_RGB/p_77672.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
            <div class="title">Dumbo</div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="length">112 min</span>
                <span class="year">2019</span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                Struggling circus owner Max Medici enlists a former star and his two children to care for Dumbo, a baby elephant born with oversized ears. When the family discovers that the animal can fly, it soon becomes the main attraction bringing in huge audiences and revitalizing the run-down circus. The elephant's magical ability also draws the attention of V.A. Vandevere, an entrepreneur who wants to showcase Dumbo in his latest, larger-than-life entertainment venture.
                <a target="_blank" class="info-btn color small" href="https://www.dolby.com/us/en/cinema"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Play Trailer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movie">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODVjZThlMzMtZjQwNy00YjRlLWE5ZTMtMWVlMWUwM2U1NjRkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODcyODY1Mzg@._V1_UY1200_CR90,0,630,1200_AL_.jpg" alt="" class="poster" />
            <div class="title">The Happy Prince</div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="length">105 min</span>
                <span class="year">2018</span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                His body ailing, Oscar Wilde lives out his last days in exile, observing the difficulties and failures surrounding him with ironic detachment, humour, and the wit that defined his life.
                <a target="_blank" class="info-btn color small" href="https://www.dolby.com/us/en/cinema"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Play Trailer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="detail">
        <svg class="close">
            <use xlink:href="#close"></use>
        </svg>
        <div class="movie">
            <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-room.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
            <div class="title">Room</div>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="length">117 min</span>
                <span class="year">2015</span>
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                Jack is a young boy of 5 years old who has lived all his life in one room. He believes everything within it are the only real things in the world. But what will happen when his Ma suddenly tells him that there are other things outside of Room?
                <a target="_blank" class="info-btn color small" href="https://www.dolby.com/us/en/cinema"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Play Trailer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a class="popup-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMBFSGVi1c">Trailer Popup</a>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
/*Card APP*/

/*-------------------- Body --------------------*/
 *, *::before, *::after {
     box-sizing: border-box;

}

/*-------------------- App --------------------*/
 .app {
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     width: 80vw;
     height: 390px;
     background: #fff;
     border-radius: 15px;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
 .app h3 {
     color: #525661;
     font-size: 17px;
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     padding: 20px 28px 0;
     margin: -6px 0 0 0;
}

/*-------------------- Movies --------------------*/
 .movies {
     display: flex;
     padding: 8px 18px;
}
 .movies .movie {
     padding-right:10%;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .movies .movie .poster {
     width:11vw;
     margin-bottom: 6px;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
 .movies .movie .poster.active {
     opacity: 0;
}
 .movies .movie .title {
     color: #525661;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 .movies .movie .info {
     font-size: .95vmax;
     opacity: 0.8;
     color: #8b9095;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
 .movies .movie .desc {
     display: none;
}
/*-------------------- Detail --------------------*/
 .detail {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     z-index: 10;
     padding: 37px 30px 30px 255px;
     display: none;
}
 .detail::before {
     content: '';
     background: #fff;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     border-radius: 15px;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
}
 .detail .close {
     position: absolute;
     top: 21px;
     right: 22px;
     width: 12px;
     height: 12px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 6px solid #fff;
     box-sizing: content-box;
     z-index: 10;
}
 .detail .poster {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     top: -10%;
     left: -6%;
     height: 100%;
     border-radius: 5px;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
     transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
}
 .detail .title, .detail .info, .detail .desc, .detail .play, .detail .close {
     transform: translateX(-50px);
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.67, 0.13, 0.1, 0.81);
}
 .detail .close {
     transform: translateX(10px);
}
 .detail .title {
     font-size: 3vmax;;
     font-weight: 300;
     color: #525661;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
}
 .detail .info {

     font-size: .95vmax;
     opacity: 0;
     margin-left: 2px;
     color: #8b9095;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
 .detail .desc {
     text-align: left;
     margin-top: 30px;
     font-size: 1.25vmax;
     line-height: 1.6;
     text-align: left;
     color: #8b9095;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
 .detail .play {
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e4761f, #ff8b32);
     border: none;
     border-radius: 20px;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 1.5;
     padding: 8px 17px;
     margin: 30px 0 0 -2px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     z-index: 10;
     outline: none !important;
     cursor: pointer;
     opacity: 0;
}
 .detail .play svg {
     vertical-align: middle;
     position: relative;
     top: -2px;
     margin-right: 3px;
}
 .detail.ready::before {
     opacity: 1;
}
 .detail.ready .info {
     opacity: 0.8;
}
 .detail.ready .poster {
     opacity: 1;
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
 .detail.ready .title, .detail.ready .info, .detail.ready .desc, .detail.ready .play, .detail.ready .close {
     transform: translateX(0);
     opacity: 1;
     transition-delay: 0s;
     transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
 .detail.ready .title {
     transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
 .detail.ready .info {
     transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
 .detail.ready .desc {
     transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
 .detail.ready .play {
     transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
 .the-most {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 50vw;
     max-width: 200px;
     padding: 10px;
}
 .the-most img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
var $play = $('.play'),
    $detail  = $('.detail'),
    $movie = $('.movie', $detail),
    $close = $('.close');

$('.movies .movie').click(function(){
  $movie.html($(this).html());
  $play.appendTo($movie);

  $poster = $('.poster', this).addClass('active');

  $('.poster', $detail).css({
    top: $poster.position().top,
    left: $poster.position().left,
    width: $poster.width(),
    height: $poster.height()
  }).data({
    top: $poster.position().top,
    left: $poster.position().left,
    width: $poster.width(),
    height: $poster.height()
  })

  $detail.show();

  $('.poster', $detail).delay(10).queue(function(next) {
    $detail.addClass('ready');

    next();
  }).delay(100).queue(function(next){
    $(this).css({
      top: '-10%',
      left: '-6%',
      width: 266,
      height: 400
    });
    next();
  })
})


/*--------------------
Close
--------------------*/
function close(){
  console.log('asd');
  $p = $('.detail .poster');
  console.log($p)
  $p.css({
    top: $p.data('top'),
    left: $p.data('left'),
    width: $p.data('width'),
    height: $p.data('height'),
  })
  $detail.removeClass('ready').delay(500).queue(function(next){
    $(this).hide();
    $poster.removeClass('active');
    next();
  });
}

$close.click(close);
$('body').click(function(e){
  $p = $(e.target).parents();
  if ($p.is('.app')){
    return false;
  } else {
    close();
  }
})


/*--------------------
Thumbnail preview
--------------------*/
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.movie:eq(0)').click();
}, 300);
setTimeout(function(){
  close();
},1700);

//popup trailer

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
    type: 'iframe'
  });
});


//---------------Mobile--------------

var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/senaru/pen/qBWYQYQ?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening and returning false on body clicks is not a good practice.
Replace your code with code below to make it work

```js
$('body').click(function(e){
  $p = $(e.target).parents();
  if ($p.is('.app')){
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('info-btn')) {
      return true
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    close();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with this:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  $p = $(e.target).parents();
  if ($p.is('.app')){
    return false; // HERE
  } else {
  close();
  }
});
```

Wouldn't this say to 'not do anything' always / anytime you click the body?

Comment it out to see. (this also seems like it might be too complcated overall)